# How to update the user 'id' and user 'profile' as superuser in custom ADMIN page in DJANGO

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, request, django-views

How can I update a user profile from a custom admin page.

I have created a custom admin dashboard in a specific page, when i click on user 'full name', i am redirected to a detail update page with the pk of the person i clicked on.

Unfortunately, using the code below, I receive the information of the the superuser logged in instead of the user from the ID clicked on.

How can I retrieve the information of the user clicked on and as the superuser update?

```
def employees_directory_profile(request, employee_pk):
    """
    Access profile of employee from Employee ListView in dashboard.
    """
    employee = get_object_or_404(Profile, pk=employee_pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST,        # Populate image data if POST
                                            request.FILES,
                                            instance=request.user.profile)

        if form.is_valid() and extended_profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            extended_profile_form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:profile')

    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=request.user)
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.profile)



    context = {
            'form':form,
            'extended_profile_form':extended_profile_form,
            'employee':employee
    }

    return render(request, 'accounts/dashboard-employee-active-profile.html', context)
```

Then when I try:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=employee)
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST,        # Populate image data if POST
                                            request.FILES,
                                            instance=employee.profile)

        if form.is_valid() and extended_profile_form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            extended_profile_form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:profile')

    else:
        form = EditProfileForm(instance=employee)
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=employee.profile)
```

I receive the error message below from the console.

```
AttributeError at /dashboard/employees-directory-profile/10
'Profile' object has no attribute 'profile'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/employees-directory-profile/10
Django Version: 2.1
Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value:    
'Profile' object has no attribute 'profile'
Exception Location: /Users/macadmin/Documents/Accel_Capital/Web_apps/accel_hr/accel_hr/accounts/views.py in employees_directory_profile, line 212
Python Executable:  /Users/macadmin/Documents/Accel_Capital/Web_apps/accel_hr/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.0
Python Path:    
['/Users/macadmin/Documents/Accel_Capital/Web_apps/accel_hr/accel_hr',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python37.zip',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7',
 '/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/macadmin/Documents/Accel_Capital/Web_apps/accel_hr/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Tue, 14 May 2019 11:24:17 -0400
Traceback Switch to copy-and-paste view
/Users/macadmin/Documents/Accel_Capital/Web_apps/accel_hr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py in inner
            response = get_response(request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/macadmin/Documents/Accel_Capital/Web_apps/accel_hr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/macadmin/Documents/Accel_Capital/Web_apps/accel_hr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py in _get_response
                response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs) ...
▶ Local vars
/Users/macadmin/Documents/Accel_Capital/Web_apps/accel_hr/accel_hr/accounts/views.py in employees_directory_profile
        extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=employee.profile)
```

models.py below:

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.urls import reverse

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

GENDER = (
        ('Male', 'Male'), 
        ('Female', 'Female'))


class Profile(models.Model):


    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthday = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)   
    gender = models.CharField(choices= GENDER, max_length=10, default='Male')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    position = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    is_terminated = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True)                   # Null = True to be removed


    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('accounts:employees-directory-profile', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    '''
    For every new user created, create new Profile.
    '''
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    else:
        instance.profile.save()
```

forms.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth import (
    authenticate,
    login,
    get_user_model

)
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserChangeForm

from .models import Profile, Document

from django.forms import ModelForm


Profile = get_user_model()


class UserLoginForm(forms.Form):
    ''' 
    Validate Login form username and password.
    '''
    username = forms.CharField()
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        username = self.cleaned_data.get('username')
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')

        if username and password:
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            if not user:
                raise forms.ValidationError('This user does not exist')
            if not user.check_password(password):
                raise forms.ValidationError('Incorrect password')
            if not user.is_active:
                raise forms.ValidationError('This user is not active')
        return super(UserLoginForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)


class UserRegisterForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ''' 
    Validate Registration form fields.
    '''
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email address')
    first_name = forms.CharField(label='First name', required=False, help_text='Optional')
    last_name = forms.CharField(label='Last name', required=False, help_text='Optional')
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)



    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password',
            'password2',
        )   

    def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        password = self.cleaned_data.get('password')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords must match")
        return super(UserRegisterForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)

class EditProfileForm(UserChangeForm):
    '''
    Edit Profile.
    '''

    class Meta:
        model = User 
        fields = (
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        # 'password1',
        # 'password2',
        'email',
        )

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ''' delete password field in edit profile page.'''
        super(EditProfileForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields.pop('password')                           



class ProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    GENDER = (
        ('Male', 'Male'), 
        ('Female', 'Female')
        )

    # image = forms.ImageField()
    birthday = forms.CharField(label='Birthday')
    location = forms.CharField(label='Location', required=False)
    gender = forms.CharField(max_length=10, widget=forms.Select(choices=GENDER))
    phone_number = forms.CharField(max_length=10)
    position = forms.CharField(label='Position', max_length=20, required=False)



    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
                'birthday', 
                'location', 
                'gender',
                'phone_number',
                'position'
        )
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the logged-in user because that's what you explicitly pass into the form. Instead you should pass the employee object you got from the database.

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = EditProfileForm(request.POST, instance=employee)
    extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST,        # Populate image data if POST
                                        request.FILES,
                                        instance=employee.profile)
    ...
else:
    form = EditProfileForm(instance=employee)
    extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=employee.profile)
```

(You should really think about renaming your models, it's not good to call the user model "profile" when that is the name of the thing that is linked to the user.)

**Edit**

This is all very confused, mainly because of your misleading form names. In your original code you had EditProfileForm editing  `request.user`, ie an instance of User, and ProfileForm editing `request.user.profile`, presumably an instance of Profile. Now `employee` is an instance of Profile, not User. So presumably you want:

```
    form = EditProfileForm(instance=employee.user)
    extended_profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=employee)
```

But really you should rename your form to UserForm so that we can understand what is actually supposed to be happening.

Comment: Yes, I tried it before and should have mentioned it in the question. please find above the message i receive from the console when it crashes.

Comment: Well you need to show your actual models then. What is the user model, and what is the profile model? Show the forms as well.

Comment: Please find the profile model and forms above edited in the question. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. It did work I will rename and make a cleaner version of this project. Thank you soooo much!!!!